# Why is fortran not computing correctly?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

```
       program partOne
       integer hit, i
       real x, y, equation, finalE, compE, finalHit
       parameter (pi = 3.1415926535)

c This program computes pi using the Monte Carlo method
         do 10 i = 1, 1000000
          x = rand()
          y = rand()
          equation = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
          if (equation .LE. 1.0) hit = hit + 1
 10    continue
       write(*,*) 'hits = ', hit
       finalHit = hit
       write(*,*) 'finalHits = ', finalHit
       finalE = ((finaHit/1000000) * 4)
       write(*,*) 'pi = ', pi
       write(*,*) 'Computed pi = ', finalE
       END PROGRAM partOne
```

Why does finalE not calculate correctly? Everything seems to assign correctly, but when the equation is done it comes out completely wrong. It should be close to pi.

> Updated:

```
       program partOne
       integer hit, i
       real x, y, equation, finalE, compE, finalHit
       parameter (pi = 3.1415926535)

c This program computes pi using the Monte Carlo method
       hit = 0
         do 10 i = 1, 1000000
          x = rand()
          y = rand()
          equation = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
          if (equation .LE. 1.0) hit = hit + 1
 10    continue
       write(*,*) 'hits = ', hit
       finalHit = hit
       write(*,*) 'finalHits = ', finalHit
       finalE = ((finaHit/1000000.0) * 4.0)
       write(*,*) 'pi = ', pi
       write(*,*) 'Computed pi = ', finalE
       END PROGRAM partOne
```

> Results after update:

```
 hits =       785524
 finalHits =    785524.00    
 pi =    3.1415927    
 Computed pi =  -5.21399923E+23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hit = hit + 1`.  `hit` can be initialized to `0` or some other value depending on your compiler and other options.  Add `hit = 0` before the loop where you increment it.

`finalE = ((finaHit/1000000) * 4)` should be `finalE = ((finalHit/1000000.0) * 4.0)`.  `finaHit` is not defined so change it to `finalHit`.  `real` values should be multiplied and added to `real` values, add the `.0` to make them real.

Making these changes:

```
 $ a.out
 hits =       785524
 finalHits =    785524.000
 pi =    3.14159274
 Computed pi =    3.14209604
```

Comment: I've tried making the changes in my updated code that you recommended. But it is not giving me the result you got. What have I missed out of your recommendations? I really apologize. I've been on the computer too long today and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I really appreciate the help

Comment: I added my updated code to the original question btw.

Comment: `finalHit` is real, so `finalHit/1000000` is a real expression and equivalent to `finalHit/1000000.0`.

Comment: I do understand the real vs integer. That completely makes sense, but I thought my updated code made the correct changes, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @XXIV you still have the typo of `finaHit` vs `finalHit`.  The "l" is missing

Comment: Wow, thanks. Like I said it has been a long day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is why you always include `implicit none`